# How to Set the default value to "checked" in a Checkbox from a database

Tags: php, mysql

In short form, users have checkbox values stored in a MySQL database.  I can loop through the database to display the VALUES (Skills_ID + Skills_Name) for each checkbox so the user can add their skills; however, I'm not able to populate these checkboxes with the default value marked "checked" for those skills already in the database.

A box full of karma for anyone who can help me get to bed tonight.  :)

Here is my code:

```
     function isChecked() {
            $query = "select * FROM individual_skills WHERE Ind_ID = ".$_SESSION['Ind_ID']. "";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());        
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                // If value exists, set $valueExitsInDB to true
                if (isset($row['Skills_ID'])) {
                    $valueExitsInDB="TRUE";
                } else {
                    $valueExitsInDB="FALSE";
                }
                    // if the value does exist, then we are writing 'checked' in the checkbox       
                    if ($valueExitsInDB) {
                        return "checked";
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
            } // END WHILE LOOP
        } // END FUNCTION
```

And, my code within the checkbox loop looks like this (no need to burden you with reading the loop as I can safely pull the checkbox values to the output -- just not the default value):

```
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skill_ID' checked='isChecked()'>". $skillName ."";
```

So, you can see, I'm calling the function with:  isChecked().

Any, and all help, very much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `$skill_ID` to your function and checking that in your query? Better yet if you already have a query to get the skills from the database why not pull the checked value in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code, assuming I understand what you are trying to do:

- You are not actually calling the function `isChecked()` as you believe; it is simply the string `"isChecked()"` being added to the output. If you checked the resulting HTML you would notice this. The line should read:

  ```
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skill_ID'" .
      (isChecked($skill_ID) ? " checked='checked'" : "") . "'> $skillname";
  ```
- As you notice above, you should pass the skill ID to the `isChecked()` function. You should then check this row in the query, not *whether there is any `Skills_ID` set in the returned query. Otherwise you are checking whether *any* skill is defined for that individual! So your function should now read:

  ```
  function isChecked($skill_ID)
  {
      $query = "SELECT 1 FROM individual_skills WHERE Ind_ID = " . 
          $_SESSION['Ind_ID'] . " AND Skills_ID = $skill_ID";

      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      return mysql_num_rows($result) = 1;
  }
  ```

---

A couple of side notes:

- I am returning either a false or true value from the function. This is in line with the naming "is..." which will return a yes or no. The caller (the `echo` statement) can then decide what to do with the returned value.
- You probably don't have to hit the database 1000 times like you are doing now. If you change your initial query to include an `isChecked` column you won't need the function and additional queries in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.  Trying to implement.

Comment: That worked.  I was nearly solidified that I may have to sleep on this; thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like below.

***Method 1***

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skill_ID'  checked='".isChecked()."'>". $skillName ."";
```

***Method 2***

you can just try

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skill_ID ".isChecked().">". $skillName ."";
```

## Explanation

***Method 1***

```
checked="checked"
```

should be a different attribute rather than putting it into the value

***Method 2***

Also addding just `checked` would do the trick for you too.

## Advice

Rather than making a database call for each check box try to make an array that would contain all the data for you. Try muti-dimensional array.

Comment: now, all checkboxes are checked.  Must be an error in my logic!  Gosh, just when I thought sleep was close.  :)

Comment: Actually what you point out in the explanation is not the problem. The problem is the output would contain the string `isChecked()` and not call the function. (It was never part of the `value` attribute.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind, thoughtful, and very organized assistance.  I've adjusted my code to Method 1 but, alas, all checkboxes are clicked.  To be so close yet so far.

Comment: isset($row['Skills_ID']) looks fishy to me. start debugging from there

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skill_ID'" . isChecked() . ">" . $skillName . "";
```

Try to use this

Comment: now, all checkboxes are checked.  Must be an error in my logic!  Gosh, just when I thought sleep was close.  :)

Comment: please check $row['Skills_ID'] for each input checkbox . Is its return false for any

Answer (score 1):

i think ,your `error(all checked checkboxes)` is because of **isset**,
instead of `isset($row['Skills_ID'])` use `!empty($row['Skills_ID'])` or `!is_null($row['Skills_ID'])` because if the field is null then also it will give you true,
see here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: gave it my boy scouts try . . . still all showing checked.  I agree. It must be in my logic with the isset / empty . . . I'm trying to say if the Ind_ID has Skills_ID in the row, then it is TRUE....